# WOULD + INF + ING VERB

Tags: grammar

Can you explain me why we use WOULD + INF + ING VERB in the following sentence:

Zuckenberg announced last months that Meta avators **would** at last **be getting** legs ?

Is this the same ?

Zuckenberg announced last months that Meta avators would at last **get** legs ?

Can you explain me when to use the structure infinitif + ing verb ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about "infinitive + ing": this is simply the choice between a simple and a continuous tense, within the scope of the modal "would".

As usual with aspectual distinctions in English, there is no difference in the objective events described, but only in how the speaker/writer is choosing to characterize them in time.

Generally using the "-ing" form locates the temporal focus at the time the activity is happening, whereas the simple form does not set a temporal focus. But I'm finding it hard to explain the (very slight) difference here. I think the *be getting* form is much more common in this sort of example, and perhaps suggests that it is part of an unfolding plan, rather than an isolated event.

Comment: In response to your comment "I thought it was not possible to use ING after an infinitive": Part of the reason that many grammarians now regard English as having only two tenses (past and non-past) is that most of the other constructions traditionally referred to as tenses can be employed independently, and combined (though they have to be in the right order).